# Raspberry controlled fraction collector - what would be the best set?

Tags: python, servo, dc-motor, diy

I was thinking about building a self-assembled easy to use fraction collector controlled by raspberry.

A Fraction collector is a piece of equipment used in liquid chromatography which has some tubes or holes and moves every some time to the next tube / hole.

I was thinking about two servos one moving in X plane and one in Y plane but I don't know that piece of equipment would be the best - step motors, micro-servos or maybe even something else.

I would like to use python to program time required to gather single fraction and move one or the other servo X or Y position.

Could someone suggest me a good starting point?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a device that needs precision, I would use a stepper motor, if a direct drive were absolutely required. In addition, I would have something that the Raspberry Pi could sense to know that the disk was in position.

If the number of positions is constant, I think a very simple mechanical device known as [The Geneva Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_drive) would be better. It was originally designed for watches. Using a motor at a constant rate of rotation, this would bring a new hole under your collector at equal and periodic intervals. You could use just an inexpensive DC motor and controller (or a servo motor) to drive the disk.

If your intervals are not strictly periodic, then you could stop the motor until the hole was ready to move again.

In any case I would use a sensor to detect when the hole was in place so that the collector could fill the test-tube or whatever you have waiting for it. This same sensor could also allow the Raspberry Pi to stop the motor until the the collector is ready with a new faction.

It would also be good to have some sort of sensor so that you don't overfill the containers.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to go for two stepper/servo motors depending on the rpm and rate of commands you plan to give to the motor with Ir speed controller 
[image]

[TO choose motor click here](https://www.lifewire.com/stepper-motor-vs-servo-motors-selecting-a-motor-818841)
Motor is completely application specific and output dependent weather precise movement or timing controlled movements

Comment: I will check it. Usually I would need to change the position by few mm every 0.5 - 5 min. Depends on the flow rate and fractionation volume. Thanks.

Comment: then I would suggest stepper motor for your environment